# Setting limits & offsets with import.io

Tags: api, import.io, kimono

I'm looking at moving over from kimonolabs to import.io since they're now shutting down soon. I have 2 questions related to import.io and parameters which are allowed when making api requests.

1 - Is it possible to set to set limits for the data being returned? I.e. with kimono you could use `&kimlimit=5` to make sure that only 5 records are returned each time when you make an api call.

2 - Is it possible to set an offset for the data being returned? I.e. with kimono you could set the offset using `&kimoffset=5` this would get the data from 0 - 5 and so on and so on as you increase the number in the parameter.

I was just wondering if this is possible with import.io and if not what would be the alternative for these two features.

Thanks.